# Names of nodes do not display properly

Tags: neo4j

I am new in Neo4j and during of creating a graph I found out that my nodes do not showing whole name but just a part of it followed by “...”, like “System of...” and I do not need to have 10 nodes with name “System of...”.
 I have tried to change a size of nodes but it does not seem that it got better.
Could you please help me to show a bigger part of the name?

Comment: Is this the web browser UI? There is not much you can do there, I think. However, you might give a try to the freshly released Neo4j Desktop app, which has a new visualization system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create your own style sheet (.grass) file to control the size, colour and labels that are displayed? e.g.

```
node.System {
    diameter: 90px;
      color: #cc9966;
      text-color-internal: #000000;
  border-color: #993300;
  caption: '(System) {name}';
}
```

The other consideration is how to model this. If all your nodes are actually Systems you could simply add the label 'System to the nodes and then you don't need to name them 'System of ...'

i.e.

```
//Find all nodes beginning with 'System of' and add the label 'System' to them
MATCH (node)
WHERE node.name STARTS WITH "System of"
SET node:System
RETURN node
```

Comment: There are same nodes that are named System of, but also different ones and it is necessary that it contains System of.
But my question was rather related to the fact, that on the all screenshots and all videos nodes contains longer strings then my do.
Thus do you think that it is normal that there are triple dots after second word?

Comment: It is normal.
Using stylesheet (.grass) - 80px diameter with 10 point text I get 57 characters before the '...'

'System of' implies that there should be 2 or more entities and a relationship e.g. System of Systems' would be represented by System type with relationship between 2 or more them. This way the name is short + typing correct.